# Typescript Error Passing a component in Event Emitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that is a control I want to hold this actual control in a list of controls.

I am trying to pass the current component in my event emitter

```
@Output() passthings: EventEmitter,<{any, MyComponent}> new EventEmitter();
```

Then in my method

```
loadStuff(){
var component = this;
this.service.getStuff().subscribe(response =>{
this.passthings.emit({response, component}); <-----Errors here
}
```

the word response is underlined with the error
"Argument of type '{response is not assignable to parameter of type '{any: any; MyComponent: any;}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@Output() passthings: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

---

Or **maybe** you can define an interface...

```
interface myEmittedObject{
    response: any;
    control: any;
}
```

...and the EventEmitter like this

```
@Output() passthings: EventEmitter<myEmittedObject> = new EventEmitter<myEmittedObject>();
```

The interface could be nested to be more detailed:

```
interface myEmployeeData {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    active: boolean;
    ...etc.
}

interface myEmittedObject{
    response: myEmployeeData ;
    control: any;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the solutions you've mentioned but they dont work. The object I am trying the EventEmitter object to cast to has properties such as id, age, active etc. When I hover above, it gives this error 

Type 'EventEmitter<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee': id, name, age, active

Comment: I just edited my answer to narrow the problem down. Try displaying the `response` object in console to have an idea of the type ....maybe is a `string` and needs to be parsed with something like `JSON.parse()`. It will be helpful to share more of your code ...or even better, a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example so I can understand the problem.